# Gamma Spectroscopy Scintillator for X-ray Fluorescence

Tags: spectroscopy, x-rays, gamma-rays

I have been reading into X-ray and gamma spectroscopy. I have found that they can both be done with scintillation detectors and work off similar principles.

That is to say that when a sample is bombarded with high amounts of radiation, electrons will be excited, and electrons from other shells will fill the spot of the excited electrons. The ejected photons from this event then hit a scintillator, turning it into light (usually a NaI crystal), which is then turned into an electrical signal via a photomultiplier tube. It is then possible to ascertain the identity of the element using modern analysis tools.

My question is:

1. Is it possible for a scintillation probe meant for gamma spectrometry to be used to perform X-ray spectroscopy and identify the chemical composition of samples
2. What would be different and have to be modified for such a setup to work with X-rays instead of radioactive isotopes?

Comment: X-rays come from electronic transitions. Gammas come from nuclear transitions. They are not separate energy ranges but separate photon generation mechanisms, and x-ray vs gamma energies overlap tremendously. Now, a given detector will have an efficiency vs photon energy curve, so one needs to examine what their experiment needs.

Comment: I see I shall specify in my post. I should've asked if it would be possible for the gamma spectrometer scintillator to identify the chemical composition of a sample but instead using X-rays. This is what is "needed."

Comment: So you want to do x-ray fluorescence measurements? If so, you need to know if the scintillator has reasonable efficiency and energy resolution over the energy range of interest. The scintillator does not care how the photon was made.

Comment: Great thank you